# How I can make my virtual device support applications that require more than 2.5MB?

Tags: android, virtual, device

Apparently my app needs 2.5 MB (maybe because my photos need 2MB...) and then virtual device can't work with that much MB.

How can I make my virtual device support more than 2.5 MB to get my application working?

Comment: Please spellcheck before sending. Also, one question mark is enough. We're not writing Spanish either, so no need for them at the beginning.

Comment: what? i dont understand what u mean...

Comment: of application... images, code, etc...

Answer (score 1):

I am going to deduce from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3824279/problems-with-hellogridview-tutorial-from-android-developer-site) that you are referring to this error message:

> E/dalvikvm-heap( 248): 2621440-byte external allocation too large for this process.

I would suggest [Googling that phrase](http://google.com/search?q=external+allocation+too+large+for+this+process) and looking at solutions to the problem which apparently can be summarised as:

- Use smaller images that are suitable for the size of an Android device
- [Resample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue/823966#823966) your [images](http://www.memofy.com/memofy/show/1008ab7f2836ab7f01071c2dbfe138/outofmemory-exception-when-decoding-with-bitmapfactory)

Comment: then why other applications of the market haves more than 2.5MB ?

Comment: Other applications on the Market presumably don't attempt to allocate more than 2.5MB to an individual `Bitmap`. Don't do that (i.e. read the above) and see what happens.  Also, you can always check other open source applications to see what they do, like the Android photo gallery app.

Comment: no no, my bitmaps only have 300kb each, 2.5mb is all the application

Comment: The size of your APK is irrelevant. The error message and links I provided suggest that you're using up more than 2.5MB of memory when decoding an image file into a `Bitmap`, by allocating too many bits-per-pixel or something similar.  The compressed image size (300kB) isn't necessarily the same as the uncompressed bitmaps size.

Comment: any idea of max resolution in a android image?